# Is it possible to insert if-else in each instruction of LLVM-IR Pass?

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

I am a beginner of LLVM-IR Pass.
Now I want to insert a code snippet in each IR Instruction.
The code snippet is equal to below:

```
if (a==1) func1();
else func2();
```

a is a global variable.

But now I encounter several Errors, mostly like:
"Instruction has bogus parent pointer!"
"Basic Block in function 'main' does not have terminator!"

I need to know that if my idea that insert these code into each instruction is feasible or not.
Thanks for help!

I have tried to tackle this problems by chatgpt, but failed

I expect somebody to tell me if this idea is feasible, i don't care how difficult it would be.

```
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct InsertConditionalCallsPass : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    InsertConditionalCallsPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      Module *M = F.getParent();
      LLVMContext &Context = M->getContext();

      FunctionCallee Func1 = M->getOrInsertFunction("func1", Type::getVoidTy(Context));
      FunctionCallee Func2 = M->getOrInsertFunction("func2", Type::getVoidTy(Context));


      GlobalVariable *VarA = M->getNamedGlobal("a");
      if (!VarA) return false; 

    for (auto BI = F.begin(), BE = F.end(); BI != BE;) {
    BasicBlock &BB = *BI++;
    auto II = BB.begin();


    if (II == BB.end()) continue;


    Instruction *Inst = &*II;
    BasicBlock *OldBB = Inst->getParent();
    BasicBlock *CondBB = OldBB->splitBasicBlock(Inst);
    OldBB->getTerminator()->eraseFromParent();

    BasicBlock *ThenBB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "then", &F, CondBB);
    BasicBlock *ElseBB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "else", &F, CondBB);
    BasicBlock *MergeBB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "ifcont", &F);

    IRBuilder<> Builder(OldBB);
    Value *LoadedA = Builder.CreateLoad(VarA->getType()->getPointerElementType(), VarA);
    Value *Cond = Builder.CreateICmpEQ(LoadedA, Builder.getInt32(1));
    Builder.CreateCondBr(Cond, ThenBB, ElseBB);

    // Then block
    Builder.SetInsertPoint(ThenBB);
    Builder.CreateCall(Func1, {});
    Builder.CreateBr(MergeBB);

    // Else block
    Builder.SetInsertPoint(ElseBB);
    Builder.CreateCall(Func2, {});
    Builder.CreateBr(MergeBB);

    // Merge block
    Builder.SetInsertPoint(MergeBB);
    Builder.CreateBr(CondBB);

    BB.getInstList().splice(MergeBB->begin(), BB.getInstList(), Inst);
    }

      return true;
    }
  };
}

char InsertConditionalCallsPass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<InsertConditionalCallsPass> X("insert-conditional-calls", "Insert Conditional Calls in Functions", false, false);
```